# Try to assign twice to the same array variable in Tensorflow

Tags: python, arrays, tensorflow, variable-assignment

I created a simple array variable in Tensorflow and I am trying to find a way to do assignment more then one time. I know that in order to do assignments in TF you need to use `tf.assign` function. The problem is that it returns a "sliced type" and not a variable type.

Code example:

```
a = [-1.2, -5, 30.0, -7.5, 0.75]
v = tf.get_variable("v", shape=[5], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(a))
s = tf.Session()
c = c[0].assign(55) # Now c is not a regular variable anymore.
print(c)  # <tf.Tensor 'strided_slice/_assign:0' shape=(5,) dtype=float32_ref>
s.run(c)  # output: array([ 55.  ,  -5.  ,  30.  ,  -7.5 ,   0.75], dtype=float32)
c = c[0].assign(66)  # Trying to assign again to index 0 of array c
```

For the last line I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File 
"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 714, in assign
raise ValueError("Sliced assignment is only supported for variables")
ValueError: Sliced assignment is only supported for variables
```

My question is what is the proper way to do more than one assignment into a variable in Tensorflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply don't reuse the same python variable `c` for different operations:

```py
a = [-1.2, -5, 30.0, -7.5, 0.75]
c = tf.get_variable("v", shape=[5], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(a))

assign55 = c[0].assign(55)
assign66 = c[0].assign(66)
assign77 = c[1].assign(77)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

  sess.run(assign55)
  print(sess.run(c))  # [55.   -5.   30.   -7.5   0.75]

  sess.run(assign66)
  print(sess.run(c))  # [66.   -5.   30.   -7.5   0.75]

  sess.run(assign77)
  print(sess.run(c))  # [66.   77.   30.   -7.5   0.75]
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem when you want to change different indexes in the array. I want to be able to assign to more then one place in the same array.

Comment: Nothing stops you from using different indices. I don't see a problem here

Comment: In your example, if I change 'assign66' variable to be :
assign66 = c[1].assign(66)

Then I will get two different versions of the modified array, one where the value at the zero index is changed ( assign55) and another where the value at the first index is changed (assign66) . I want one version where both cells are modified.

Comment: @tomer.golany I'm afraid, you're wrong, only one array is modified. I have updated the answer to work with difference indices

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, You're right :) . is there a way to that without running all the assignment variables. (Only running c or one of the assignment variables)
Thanks!

Comment: I guess you have to run an op to make any change. But you can run two or more of them simultaneously, which will do it just as fast as one op

Comment: Thank you so much!